Does there exist an Aronszajn line that is isomorphic to any open interval within it?
I'm self-studying Aronszajn trees and am trying to now make sense of Aronszajn lines. The main question I have is: do there exist Aronszajn lines that, like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$, are isomorphic to every open interval within?
Clearly not all Aronszajn lines are like this, as you can just add a bunch of stuff off to the end of one and get another Aronszajn line, which technically satisfies the axioms of not having any uncountable subset order-isomorphic to $\omega_1,$ the reverse of $\omega_1$ or a subset of $\Bbb R$. So if $A$ is an Aronszajn line, then so is $A + 1$, $A + \omega$, etc. So the question is mostly if there are very nicely behaved Aronszajn lines which are "homogeneous" in the sense above, which we could perhaps build the rest from. And if so, if we can "construct" one in perhaps a mildly-non-constructive-but-still-reasonable sense using the axiom of choice.

We assume there is an Aronszajn tree $T$ such that every node has an immediate successor and:
For any two nodes $\sigma,\tau\in T$ the tree $T_\sigma=\{\rho\in T:\sigma\subseteq \rho\}$ and above $T_\tau=\{\rho\in T:\tau\subseteq \rho\}$ are isomorphic. This is equivalent to asking that for all $\sigma \in T$ the entire tree $T$ is isomorphic to $T_\sigma=\{\rho\in T:\sigma\subseteq \rho\}$
We sketch a proof that there exists an Aronszajn line with the desired properties. Let $\widehat{T}$ be the tree of pairs of sequences $(\tau_0,\tau_1)$ such that $\tau_1\in T$ and $\tau_0:ht(\tau_1)+1\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ with finite support, and order $\widehat{T}$ with the lexicographic order. We have that $\widehat{T}$ with the relation $(\tau_0,\tau_1)\prec (\sigma_0,\sigma_1)$ if and only if $\tau_i\subsetneq \sigma_i$ for $i=0,1$ is still an Aronszajn tree so its lexicographic order will be an Aronszajn line. We have that $\widehat{T}$ has the following properties:
(1) The $\subseteq$-immediate-successors of any $a\in \widehat{T}$ are a dense linear order without endpoints with respect to the lexicographic order.
(2) $\widehat{T}\cong\mathbb{Q} \times \widehat{T}\cong \mathbb{Q}\times (\{pt\}+\widehat{T})$. In particular for any $x\in \widehat{T}$ we have that $\widehat{T}_x\setminus\{x\}=\{y\in\widehat{T}: x\prec y\}$ is order isomorphic to $\widehat{T}$
(3)  For all $\alpha<\omega_1$, $\alpha\times (\{pt\}+\widehat{T})\cong \{pt\}+\widehat{T}$.
Let $U\subseteq \widehat{T}$ be an open non empty $<_{lex}$ interval, we consider the case in which $U=(a,b)_{<_{lex}}$. The general case in which $U$ is any convex set of $(\widehat{T},<_{lex})$ is obtained by noticing that any non empty convex set will be the increasing union of countably many open intervals.
Let $\beta=\min\{\alpha: a(\alpha)\neq b(\alpha)\}$. We have that $U$ will be the disjoint union of:
(i) $\widehat{T}_d$ where $d$ is a successor of $a$ or an initial segment of $a$ of height $\geq \beta$ which is not an initial segment of $b$
(ii) $\widehat{T}_d\cap U$ where $d$ is a proper initial segment of $b$ of height $\geq\beta$. We note that $\widehat{T}_d\cap U\cong \{pt\}+\widehat{T}$.
Let $\gamma$ be such that $lv(b)=\beta+\gamma$, we have $U\cong (\mathbb{Q}+\gamma)\times(\{pt\}+ \widehat{T})$ so $U\cong \widehat{T}$ by observation (2) and (3).
To construct such a tree $T$ of strictly increasing bounded sequences of rationals with the desired properties we follow the classic construction for a $\omega_1$ Aronszajn tree (see Jech 2008) and require that the construction carried out above an given $x\in T$ is essentially the same as the procedure you carry above the empty sequence.
Edit:
By induction we define $T$ level by level, let $T_\alpha$ denote all the sequences of height $\leq \alpha$. We choose for each $r\in \mathbb{R}$ a order isomorphism $f_r$ between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: q>r\}$. We require that for every $\tau,\sigma \in T$ that  $\sigma\in T\leftrightarrow \tau^\frown (f_{\sup\tau}\circ \sigma)\in T$.  Let $T_0=\{\emptyset\}$. Given $T_\alpha$ we set $T_{\alpha+1}=T_\alpha\cup\{\sigma^\frown(q):q>\sup(\sigma)\}$.
For the limit case assume that for all $\gamma<\alpha$ we have defined $T_\gamma$. We have that for every $\sigma\in T_{<\alpha}\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha}T_\gamma$ and $q>\sup \sigma$ there exists a branch $g$ in $T_{<\alpha}$ of length $\alpha$ extending $\sigma$ such that $\sup \bigcup \sigma<q$ (Property 9.11 Jech)
There are two possible cases. The first case is that there exists a $\gamma<\alpha$ such that there is a $\delta<\alpha$ and $\alpha=\beta+\delta$. That is $\alpha$ is decomposable. In such case let
$\beta=\min\{\gamma<\alpha:\exists \delta <\alpha \gamma+\delta=\alpha\}$. The construction in such case is forced. Let $\delta$ be such that $\beta+\delta=\alpha$. For each $\sigma\in T_\beta$ and $\tau\in T_\delta$ we add to $T$ the sequence $\sigma^\frown (f_{\sup \sigma}\circ \tau)$.
If instead $\alpha$ is not decomposable, then we for each $\sigma\in T_{<\gamma}$ and $q>\sup \sigma$ we choose a branch $g$ of $T_{<\alpha}$ of length $\alpha$ extending $\sigma$ with $\sup g<q$ and add it to $T$.
The tree $T=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} T_\alpha$ will be the wanted tree.
The answer is already a bit long but can write out more details if needed.

Thanks - I don't 100% follow but I'll see if I can go through this... do you know if the resulting line is unique? Or how many such lines there are?

@MikeBattaglia I have no idea. I think you might be able to show with the existence of a Suslin tree that such a line is not unique up to order isomorphism but I am very not sure.
